# Comma usage in compound sentence with adverb phrase

Tags: commas

Is the following punctuated correctly?

**A.** There is a bird that chirps outside my window, and, every morning during the spring, it wakes me before my alarm goes off.

I am wondering if the adverb phrase (“every morning during the spring”) must be set off by commas. Or could the following be correct?

**B.** There is a bird that chirps outside my window, and every morning during the spring it wakes me before my alarm goes off.

Thanks.

Comment: You should avoid putting a comma both before and after *and*.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that most style guides advise separating an introductory adverbial adjunct from its main clause, but you don't need a preceding comma.  Surrounding such a construct with commas may mislead your reader into expecting an **aside**, as in:

> There is a bird that chirps outside my window, **and horrible to say**, it wakes me before my alarm goes
>   off.

Comment: So would you recommend punctuating it like this? There is a bird that chirps outside my window, and every morning during the spring, it wakes me before my alarm goes off.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the comma after "and" and keep the comma before.  The "and" is joining two separate clauses, and in my opinion is necessary:

"There is a bird that chirps outside my window, and every morning during the spring, it wakes me before my alarm goes off."

Comment: +1 [Saw that you'd popped past ELU today, nice to see you!]

Comment: Good stuff. Still teaching? Or is it doing something new?

Comment: Glad to hear things are going well!

Comment: Gravity's Rainbow! Wow, you do have a lot of spare time! I've got a copy of that somewhere -  but have never opened it. It's so big!